# ¿Qué es una función realmente?

Tags: c, funciones

¿Qué es realmente una función?, aunque esto pueda llegar a parecer muy básico tenia entendido que las funciones se utilizan únicamente para dividir el código de tal modo que cada bloque del mismo haga algo en concreto.

La duda radica en algo que escuche hoy, una tal *dirección de memoria de una función*. Pregunto entonces, si una función es simplemente un bloque de código, ¿Cómo es que tiene una dirección de memoria?

```
#include <stdio.h>

double factorial(int a);

int main()
{
    int numero;
    printf("\n\n\t\t Direccion de memoria de la funcion 'factorial'  ==>  %i",&factorial);
}

double factorial(int a)
{
    if (a == 1 || a == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return a * factorial(a - 1);
    }
}
```

El hecho de que una función tuviese una *dirección de memoria* me hizo cuestionarme lo que realmente es una función.

Comment: La CPU coge datos y código desde la RAM. Por eso las funciones tienen una dirección en memoria: es el lugar en donde reside el código de la función.

Comment: @CandidMoe ¿ lo que quiere decir que el código fuente en su totalidad se almacena también en la RAM ?

Comment: El código fuente en si no es lo que se almacena. Cuando generas los binarios, estos son los que tienen la información para ejecutar instrucciones. Al momento que ejecutas estos programas, se cargan en la RAM los datos e instrucciones necesarias.

Comment: El objeto de este sitio es responder preguntas sobre problemas concretos de programación. Lo que preguntas es más apropiado para el lugar donde estudias.

Comment: @CandidMoe supongo que ya estoy ahí, soy autodidacta.

Comment: @CandidMoe Hacer preguntas totalmente teóricas también está aceptado. A diferencia de SO en inglés, no tenemos un sitio para software engineering, code review, computer science, etc

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta varia del contexto. Pero entiendo que tu duda es sobre la relación entre la memoria física y el código que estás escribiendo.

Al final del día el código que escribes, es una 2da, 3ra, o más, abstracción de los "bits" (o considera refirerte a ellos como "el programa") que se guardarán en la memoria. Tu programa es realmente solo una serie de instrucciones. El lenguaje de programación que haz elegido, es convertido a algún momento en instrucciones para la computadora. Este programa, al ser ejecutado se mueve de tu disco duro a tu RAM. Y en este caso, cada instrucción que haz dado, tiene por consecuente un lugar en la memoria.

Una función, en este contexto, es un bloque de instrucciones que haz "nombrado". En el programa que fue compilado, al correrlo, no sabemos exactamente donde están (es decir, en que dirección) las instrucciones, pero sí sabemos que esas instrucciones estarán juntas. Hay diferentes casos de uso en donde esa información podría ser útil, pero "para que quiero saber su dirección" es una pregunta distinta.

En el ejemplo de arriba, si corres ese programa en una computadora normal, e imprimes la dirección, notarás que cambia cada vez que corres el programa. Esto es porque el sistema operativo "carga" tu programa (aka, tus instrucciones) de acuerdo a su esquema de manejo de memoria. Es decir lo muevo de tu disco duro a la memoria RAM. Cada vez que lo haga será colocado donde el esquema de manejo de memoria decida que es más conveniente.

Expandiendo solo un poco más, un ejemplo de cuando es útil: cuando he trabajado con lenguaje ensamblador, al crear [interrupciones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt#Software_interrupts) necesito decirle al sistema a donde dirigirse cuando esta suceda, en este caso, la dirección de la "función", o mejor llamado en este contexto "bloque instrucciones", es donde el programa debe continuar. En este contexto también lo llamaríamos una "subrutina". Esto es útil porque no puedo saber la dirección de la función antes de correr el programa, pero el poder "apuntar" a la dirección es lo que lo permite.

Nota: Mi respuesta no es específica para C/C++. El objetivo es aclarar la idea, no la implementación en alguna arquitectura específica.

Comment: *Has elegido*, *has dado*... revisa un poco la ortografía.

Comment: @PabloLozano oof....

Answer (score 3):

Ya que tu pregunta es para el lenguaje C, centraré mi respuesta en ese lenguaje.

El C es un lenguaje compilado. Esto significa que antes de poder ejecutarse un programa en C un compilador debe convertirlo a código máquina. El código máquina resultante será específico para una arquitectura de CPU concreta. Ese código máquina será finalmente enlazado con librerías del sistema y otras partes del fuente para crear con él un *ejecutable*. El formato del fichero ejecutable depende del sistema operativo para el cual haya sido generado. No es igual un ejecutable de Windows que uno de Linux, por ejemplo.

### La función en código máquina

Ya que el C se traduce a código máquina, una función C será una cierta estructura de código dentro del código máquina, una vez compilado. En concreto es una zona que contiene instrucciones (máquina) a la que se puede saltar desde otra parte del código usando la instrucción máquina `CALL`, y que puede "retornar" usando la instrucción máquina `RET` (esa instrucción volverá a la instrucción siguente a aquella que hizo `CALL`.

Todo lo que sabe el código máquina sobre funciones es esto: cómo saltar al inicio de una y cómo volver a donde estaba al encontrar `RET`. El código máquina no sabe nada de parámetros. La instrucción `CALL` del código máquina no es nada parecido a `CALL Factorial(numero)` ni siquiera `CALL Factorial, numero`. Es más bien algo como un salto relativo, como `CALL +18827` que significa básicamente "guarda por dónde íbamos y salta a la instrucción que se halla 18827 posiciones después de ésta". Aunque también admite sintaxis con direcciones absolutas como `CALL 8827381` que sería "guarda por dónde íbamos y salta a la dirección de memoria 8827387.

Para guardar "por dónde iba", la CPU usa una zona temporal de la RAM llamada la pila. En la pila se guarda la dirección de la instrucción siguiente al CALL, para que cuando más adelante se encuentre el `RET` simplemente haya que extraer de la pila la dirección guardada allí, y volver a ella.

### La carga del ejecutable

Una vez tienes el ejecutable, puedes distribuir ese y quien vaya a ejecutarlo no necesitará el código fuente. Cuando el ejecutable es ejecutado, es cargado en memoria RAM. Entonces tendrás en memoria una zona de direcciones cuyos contenidos son accesibles desde tu programa, mientras éste está en ejecución.

Esa memoria se divide típicamente en varias zonas (que corresponden a diferentes direcciones contiguas):

- La zona de datos. Contendrá las variables globales que tu programa haya declarado (no hay ninguna en tu ejemplo). Pero esas variables ya no son referenciadas desde el código máquina por su nombre, sino por sus direcciones. Los nombres son cosas del código fuente, y el compilador las habrá convertido en direcciones relativas al inicio de la zona de datos.
- La zona de código. Contendrá las instrucciones máquina resultado de la compilación de tu código C. Cada instrucción máquina ocupa una o varias posiciones de memoria (en la arquitectura Intel muchas instrucciones son varios bytes).

  Ya que C organiza el código en funciones, ese código máquina también estará organizado en funciones. Cada función comienza en una cierta dirección de memoria relativa a la zona de código. La función `main` no es más que otra de esas funciones. Cuando el ejecutable ha sido cargado, comenzará a ejecutar un código llamado el *startup* (que el compilador ha escrito por tí) y es ese codigo el que incluye un `CALL` que llama a la dirección donde esté `main`. Cuando se alcance el `RET` dentro de `main` se volverá al código del *startup*, que limpiará y liberará lo que haya que liberar y finalmente terminará el proceso.
- Además hay otra zona para la PILA que está muy relacionada con la ejecución de funciones, como hemos visto. La zona de PILA no es más que otra zona de la memoria a la que se accede mediante un juego de instrucciones específico (que no usarás nunca explícitamente en tu código C, pero que está en el código máquina que el compilador ha generado). Además de la instrucción `CALL` que como se ha dicho usa la pila para guardar la dirección de retorno, la CPU cuenta con las instrucciones PUSH y POP. PUSH que permite meter un dato en la pila "encima" de los que ya hubiera, y POP permite extraer el dato "encima" de la pila (es decir, el último que haya sido introducido). Estas instrucciones permiten reciclar esas posiciones de la memoria, ya que si haces PUSH y luego POP, habrás metido un dato y lo habrás extraído, con lo que la pila volverá a estar "vacía". Un nuevo PUSH reutilizará la misma dirección que había usado el primer PUSH. Por tanto la pila es un almacén temporal.

  El compilador C usa la pila (internamente, sin que tú tengas por qué saberlo) para dos propósitos:

  - Almacenar allí los parámetros que se le pasan a una función antes de llamarla
  - Almacenar allí todas las variables locales que use la función

  Estos elementos, junto con la dirección de retorno forman lo que se llama un *marco de pila*. Cada vez que se llama a una función se crea uno de estos marcos en la pila ("encima" de los que ya hubiera) para los parámetros y variables de la función a la que se va a llamar. Cada vez que la función retorna, se destruye el correspondiente marco. Es un uso inteligente de la pila, ya que de este modo los parámetros y variables locales sólo están ocupando memoria mientras el marco esté en la pila. Una vez el marco se ha destruido esos parámetros y variables ya no ocupan memoria. Además el orden en que los marcos van "uno encima de otro" es conveniente para deshacerlo al revés de cómo se creó, lo que tiene sentido porque la primera función de la que se retornará es precisamente la última a la que se ha llamado.

### Explicación entonces de una llamada

Cuando tu código C hace por ejemplo:

```
result = factorial(numero);
```

El compilador traduce eso a una serie de instrucciones máquina que en esencia hacen:

1. Acceder a la dirección de memoria donde está la variable `numero` para extraer su valor. Digamos que ese valor es 5.
2. Meter ese valor (5) en la cima de la pila (preparando así el parámetro que se le va a pasar a la función)
3. Efectuar un CALL a la dirección de memoria donde comienza la función `factorial` (eso mete en la pila la dirección de retorno, encima de los parámetros que había antes)

A partir de ese punto la ejecución prosigue por el interior de la función `factorial`, que hará lo siguiente:

- **a** Comenzará con código para crear las variables locales de esa función (metiéndolas también en la pila, encima de lo que hubiera). Este código lo ha metido el compilador.
- **b** Código adicional para acceder a la pila y obtener los valores de los parámetros (sin necesidad de sacar lo que había en ella, sino "mirando" debajo de las cosas apiladas y debajo de la dirección de retorno). Encuentra allí un 5.
- **c** Efectúa el resto de instrucciones que haya en la función, en este caso calculando el factorial de 5.
- **d** Cuando se dispone a retornar, elimina de la pila todas las variables locales (en la cima de la pila hay ahora la dirección de retorno)
- **e** Se copia el valor a retornar (lo que en C hayas puesto tras `return`) en un registro de la CPU. En este ejemplo, el factorial de 5 es 120 por lo que ese será el dato que queda en el registro de la CPU.
- **f** Se efectúa un `RET` (en código máquina no lleva parámetros) que saca de la pila la dirección de retorno y salta a esa dirección

A partir de aquí se ha vuelto al programa principal, concretamente a la siguiente instrucción máquina que iba tras el CALL. A continuación se hace lo siguiente:

4. Se eliminan de la pila los parámetros introducidos en el paso 2 (o sea, el 5 que metimos entonces). La pila vuelve a estar vacía (o vuelve a estar tal como estaba en el marco, antes de la llamada).
5. Se recoge del registro de la CPU el valor allí guardado por la función (en el paso **e**) y se guarda en la dirección de memoria de la variable `resultado`. En este caso se guardaría 120.

Esto completaría la ejecución de la función.

### Usos

Como ves, a nivel de código máquina, cada función tiene un punto de entrada que está en una cierta dirección de memoria, que es necesario conocer para la instrucción CALL del código máquina. El compilador C te permite obtener qué dirección es esa aplicando el operador `&` al nombre de la función, del mismo modo que puede usar ese operador sobre el nombre de una variable para obtener la dirección de memoria de la variable.

El hecho de que puedas obtener la dirección de una función en C, te permite crear variables que guarden esa dirección (serían *punteros a funciones*), o pasar esas direcciones como parámetro (así podrías escribir funciones que reciben como parámetro la dirección de otra función).

Si tienes un puntero a función (o un parámetro que es un puntero a función) llamado por ejemplo `p`, puedes usar el valor de ese puntero para invocar la función, escribiendo `p()`. Por ejemplo:

```
    double (*p)(int);
    p = &factorial;
    printf("Factorial de 5=%f\n", p(4));
```

Observa que la parte más compleja de este ejemplo es la declaración de `p` (en la que no voy a entrar, está declarando un puntero a una función que reciba como parámetro un `int` y devuelva un `double`). Una vez tenemos correctamente declarada `p`, asignarle un valor es tan simple como `p=&factorial`, con tal de que la función que pongamos tras el `&` coincida en su prototipo con declarado para `p`.

Y observa que una vez tenemos `p` apuntando a `factorial`, podemos usar `p` para invocar `factorial`, poniendo `p(5)` por ejemplo. En este caso la instrucción máquina que se usa no es un  CALL a una dirección dada, sino una variante de CALL en la que la dirección se toma de un registro. El compilador en este caso incluirá código para copiar el valor de `p` al registro apropiado para después usar este  CALL especial.